# Circular Reference with Dependency Injection for UrlHelper / ActionContext

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I need an `UrlHelper` in my webapi vNext controller, so I am trying to get it injected using the constructor:

```
public BaseApiController(UrlHelper urlHelper)
```

In my Startup.cs I've added:

```
services.AddTransient<UrlHelper, UrlHelper>();
```

But when I run it, it errors because it can't resolve the `ActionContext` parameter to instantiate the `UrlHelper`. So I added:

```
services.AddTransient<ActionContext, ActionContext>();
```

But then I get the error:

```
A circular dependency was detected for the service of type
'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionContext'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can use `Url.Link` for what I need, so I don't need `UrlHelper` at all. Not exactly a fix for the problem as stated, but it's worked for me.